# Is it safe to pass HTML data inside a JSON structure?

Tags: html, json, azure, asp.net-web-api2, html-encode

I have a scenario where I need to send an HTML value inside a JSON response to an API call as following :

```
{
   "ID": "1",
    "Data": {
            "Value": "<p><strong>xyz<\/strong><\/p>\n\n<p>Hello &amp; World&nbsp;<\/p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\n"
         }
}
```

my question is whether it is safe to send HTML data as string inside JSON structure to API calls or will there be any chances for the content to be blocked for example will the azure gateway block such content?

Answer (score -1):

It is fine to pass the HTML in your JSON result.
There is no restriction for this in the JSON Spec.
But take care of the below points in case the JSON is used in Browser.

1. Escape quotation marks used around HTML attributes like so `<img src=\"img.png\" />`
2. Escape the forward slash in HTML end tags. `<div>Hello World!<\/div>`. This is to handle the HTML file in Script tags.
3. Double quotes (") character should be encoded as `&quot;` , else it would break if included as HtmL content.

Comment: 1. Yes, but this is not something that should require pointing out, as it will be handled by the JSON-encoder, which everyone who produces JSON is using, *riiiiight?!* 2. Only relevant *if* this is embedded into an HTML script element. 3. Only relevant if this is embedded into an HTML *attribute*, in which case you'd be HTML-encoding it anyway, which takes care of that automatically.

Comment: @deceze, the direct answer was given and an extra explanation was given. HTML is ultimately to be rendered on some kind of Browser. right??